# Robot Detection not working?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have set the robot detection on form as true following the doc on https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/93/sitecore-experience-platform/work-with-robot-detection-for-forms.html

Then I created a selenium python script to submit the form. Its able to submit form without any issue.

My question here is how to validate/verify if robot detection is actually working or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your instance is `Standalone or ContentDelivery`, as if you review `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.RobotDetection.config` the robot detection pipelines don't run on the `ContentManagement` role.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't trust the robot detection or if it is not giving you the right functionality, you could always try and use a Recaptcha.

Sitecore Forms Extensions uses a Google Recaptcha component.
http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/sitecore-forms-extensions-for-sitecore-9-3/

In cases of my projects I had issues because of GDPR laws. It restricted the use of cookies if someone does not have accepted the cookies. This will cause Sitecore to always see a visitor as a Robot since there is no cookie to validate it with.

Comment: Thanks Danny! it helps.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know does `Sitecore` thinks the user is human, it saves true or false value to cookie `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE`.

For example if the value of cookie `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` is: `ef86f68776cf417db46dd217cc60807d|True`

Sitecore thinks the user is human. If the value is false Sitecore thinks it is a robot. You could try to read this value with the same python script and see does Sitecore thinks its a robot or not. If the value is false(robot), the problem probably lies in a form itself.

Comment: Understood, Is there any way to cross verify if robot detection I enabled is actually working other than script.